# Session variable empty after reloading page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, session, variables

I have a simple page with a drop down menu where i can select between two values, `FOO` and `BAR`. The selected value should be stored in my session Variable `$_SESSION['typ']`. It worked so far, but i noticed that everytime when I press F5 or call `location.reload()` with javascript, then the session variable is cleared for some unknown reason.

**main.php**

```
<?php
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 1);
session_set_cookie_params(0.1);

session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['typ']))
{

    $typ = "FOO";    //load default value
    $_SESSION['typ'] = $typ;
    //---Debug Output----
    $tmpvar = $_SESSION['typ'];
    echo "<p>Session variable is not set</p>";
    echo "<p>Session variable value: '$tmpvar'</p>";
}
else
{   
    //---Debug Output----
    $tmpvar = $_SESSION['typ'];
    echo "<p>Session variable is set, value = '$tmpvar' </p>";

    $typ = $_SESSION['typ'];  //initialise variable $typ with session variable
}
?>
```

Drop down menu where i can set my $typ variable.

```
    <form name="typ_overwrite" method="POST" action="set_typ.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        TYP: <select name="typ" id="typ" onchange="document.typ_overwrite.submit()">
<?php
        if($typ == "FOO")
        {
            echo '<option value="FOO">FOO</option>';
            echo '<option value="BAR" selected>BAR</option>';
        }
        elseif($typ == "BAR")
        {
            echo '<option value="BAR">BAR</option>';
            echo '<option value="FOO" selected>FOO</option>';
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<option value="ERROR">ERROR</option>';
        }
?>
        </select>
    </form>
```

**set_typ.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $typ = $_POST['typ'];
    $_SESSION['typ'] = $typ;

    header("location:main.php");
    exit();
?>
```

Output if i load the page for the first time:

> ```
> Session variable is not set
> Session variable value: 'FOO'
> ```

Output after i select BAR from the Drop Down Menu:

> ```
> Session variable is set, value: 'BAR'
> ```

Output after i press F5 or call `location.reload()`

> ```
> Session variable is not set
> Session variable value: 'FOO'
> ```

I hope someone can enlighten me why my Session variable is cleared on reloading the page.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand you right: you are starting by the page with the form. 2nd step: the form calls _set\_typ.php_, which does a re-direct to _main.php_. When you **now** press F5, the $_SESSION variable is not set?

Comment: Yes, exactly. But i found the problem, but can't really explain why it works, find my answer below please.

Comment: The reason is that **gc_maxlifetime** defines the time in **seconds** until the session data (the session variables) is regarded as garbage. Maybe you just where a bit too slow clicking ;-)

Comment: Ah i understand, it works if i set it to 1000, it seems that the source where i found the info about sessions was obsolete or incorrect. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem...
It is because this lines of code, i commented it out now it works as expected. Can someone explain where i have to set it?

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 1);
```

**EDIT**:
The reason was that **gc_maxlifetimes** parameter unit is in seconds, not in hours as i thought, so the session expired after 1 second and therefor the SESSION Variables were cleared. Kudos to hherger for pointing this out.

Comment: 0.1 means 0.1 seconds as the cookie lifetime. I'd suggest to set it to 0 (null), which means "until the client browser is closed".

Comment: Oh sry i copied the wrong line of code, i edited my answer. But you were right, it was because i was setting gc_maxlifetime to 1, after i set it to 1000 it works as expected.